# Reassigning numpy.array()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In the code below, I can easily reduce the array `['a','b','a','c','b','b','c','a']` to a binary array `[0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0]` so that `'a' -> 0` and `'b','c' -> 1`. How do I transform it to a ternary array so that `'a' -> 0`, `'b' -> 1`, `'c' -> 2`, without using `for` and `if-else`? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'])
y = np.where(x=='a', 0, 1)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing:

```
np.where(x == 'a', 0, (np.where(x == 'b', 1, 2)))
```

note that this changes all the characters that are neither 'a' or 'b' to 2. I've assumed that you have only an array with a,b and c.

Comment: You should be using `np.select` for more than a binary outcome.

Answer (score 1):

A more scalable version is using dictionary of conversion:

```
my_dict = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}
x = np.vectorize(my_dict.get)(x)
```

output:

```
[0 1 0 2 1 1 2 0]
```

Another approach is:

```
np.select([x==i for i in ['a','b','c']], np.arange(3))
```

For small dictionary @ypno's answer is going to be faster. For larger dictionary, use this answer.

---

**Time Comparison**:

**Ternary alphabet**:

```
lst = ['a','b','c']
my_dict = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(lst)}

#@Ehsan's solution1
def m1(x):
  return np.vectorize(my_dict.get)(x)

#@ypno's solution
def m2(x):
  return np.where(x == 'a', 0, (np.where(x == 'b', 1, 2)))

#@SteBog's solution
def m3(x):
  y = np.where(x=='a', 0, x)
  y = np.where(x=='b', 1, y)
  y = np.where(x=='c', 2, y)
  return y.astype(np.integer)

#@Ehsan's solution 2 (also suggested by user3483203 in comments)
def m4(x):
   return np.select([x==i for i in lst], np.arange(len(lst)))

#@juanpa.arrivillaga's solution suggested in comments
def m5(x):
  return np.array([my_dict[i] for i in x.tolist()])

in_ = [np.random.choice(lst, size = n) for n in [10,100,1000,10000,100000]]
```

[image]

**Same analysis for 8 letter alphabet**:

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
```

[image]

Comment: why use `np.vectorize`? it really should be avoided. Almost certainly, `np.array([my_dict[x] for x in array.tolist()])` will be faster.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for your suggestion. Could you please provide more information as to why _it really should be avoided. Almost certainly_? I am not aware of the implementation details, but if you think it is a bad implementation in Numpy, maybe you can raise it to the Numpy developers. However, one personal answer would be readability which is subjective. Another, is that `np.vectorize` seems to be faster for larger arrays than a list comprehension. I will add time comparison for better judgement. Thank you.

Comment: Straight from the documentation: "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Interesting. Thank you for the response. Please checkout the time analysis I updated. Seems like vectorize is slightly faster for larger arrays. Unless, I have missed something, there seems to be some sort of optimization difference in vectorize and simple loop.

Comment: likely, it's the overhead of converting to list. If I were actually doing this, I wouldn't be using a numpy.ndarray to begin with. Try it without `.tolist()`, and then try it with with a regular list, and I bet you will see, it is faster with the list comprehension.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are probably right. Do you mean `np.array([my_dict[i] for i in x])`? If so, it is slower than converting to list. IF you mean to store `x` originally as a list instead of a numpy array, that is a different assumption, and the comparison will not be fair, since `np.vectorize` applies to arrays, but depending on OP's problem, could be applicable to the question. Thank you.